# Python - Disable warnings for SecurityWarning: Certificate has no `subjectAltName`, RFC 2818

Tags: python

I'm trying to suppress the below warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:251: SecurityWarning: Certificate has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)
  SecurityWarning
```

my code is as follows

```
import requests
from orionsdk import SwisClient

#solarwinds creds
hostname = 'SolarWinds-Orion'
username = 'api'
password = 'XXXX'
v_path = '/var/www/itapp/tools/solarwinds.pem'

sites = SiteData.objects.exclude(site_type='Major Site').filter(is_live=True)
swis = SwisClient(hostname, username, password, verify=v_path)

query = """
    SELECT NodeID
          ,NodeName
          ,IPAddress
    FROM Orion.Nodes 
    WHERE NodeName LIKE '%NVR'
"""
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
existing_results = swis.query(query)
nodes = existing_results["results"]
```

My searching shows that if I issue requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(), then the warnings should be suppressed, but no matter where I put that line i always get the warning.
Am I missing something or do i need to use something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hmm, if i am not mistaken requests uses its own vendored copy of urllib3 but the warning you are getting comes directly from your installed copy of urllib3.

Try doing:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.SecurityWarning)
```

You can also handle any kind of warning generated by the [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/warnings.html) python library like this:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', urllib3.exceptions.SecurityWarning)
```

Comment: Disabling the general `SecurityWarning` will suppress all other security warnings, too. If you only want to suppress the one that was specifically asked for in the question (or any other specific one, for that matter): `urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.SubjectAltNameWarning)`